# AWS SNS dynamic subscriptions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

We have got a strange requirement and we would like to send SMS to our clients based on the assets they are monitoring. Each asset can have 100s of subscribers and there are 1000s of assets so obviously, we can not create one SNS topic per asset. We have the assets and their list of subscribers in a RDS instance on AWS.

Is there anyway with SNS to make the list of its subscribers dynamic, each time we publish a message to it we also supply the list of subscriber this message should be sent to? What are my other options or another AWS service? Lambda maybe? Please advise. thanks

Comment: I think Twilio might be a better fit.

Answer (score 5):

I finally used SNS for this purpose. Each time I need to sent an alert, I call a lambda and supple lambda with the list of subscribers and the message for that asset. Lambda will go ahead, create a new topic, add the subscribers to it, publish the message to it and when everything is done, removes the topic. Works great.

Comment: It worked well but the solution was kinda dirty. We ended up using Twilio after awhile.

Answer (score 0):

AWS SNS for sending sms had limitation like only for US or North America region. This point should be double checked before making such choice. If your users only from USA - so quite good. In other cases I would recommend to take a look on https://www.nexmo.com/, clickatell.com or Twilio. They provide nice API and can be managed very easy.

Comment: AWS actually added worldwide SMS delivery to SNS recently: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-worldwide-delivery-of-amazon-sns-messages-via-sms/ I still think it's a good idea to look at those other services though.

Comment: I see that it brend new announced by Jeff Barr on 29 JUN 2016.  In this case need to compare price politic. If price politic is close better to use AWS. Because it provide possibility manage several ways how notify - sms, push etc and can be managed in one way